# Does sorting channels in multivariate time series affect performance of CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am now learning about CNN in machine learning. Also, I am trying to apply my knowledge to my another project which involves sensors attached on the body. There are some accelerometers and gyroscopes sticking to the subject's head, hands, legs, etc. I want to use CNN that I have recently learned to recognize activities such as jumping, running, walking, so on.

I would like to know that putting sensors in different orders can affect the evaluation performance, theoretically, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can affect the evaluation performance but with a sane weight initialization scheme, the expected evaluation performance would be the same, since for every weight init $w$, permuting the channels is equivalent to permuting the channel axis of $w$.